# login access the account with incorrect username and password

Tags: php, codeigniter

In the below code i have placed controller and modl.When user is inactive he should not able to access the account and only created account users can able to access the account.But in my case it is not working like that.Pls help me to rectify the issue.
Controller:

```
function validate_credentials()
        {   $this->load->helper('url');

            $this->load->model('membership_model');
            $query = $this->membership_model->validate();

            if($query) // if the user's credentials validated...
            {
                $data = array(
                    'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
                    'is_logged_in' => true
                );
                 $data1 = array(
                    'college_name' => $this->input->post('college_name'),
                    'is_logged_in' => true
                );
                 $this->session->set_userdata($data1);
                 redirect('site1/members_area');
                if($query->num_rows()>0){
                 $status = $query->row()->account_status;}
                else {
                 $status = ''; }
                 //Account active
                if($status == 'active')
                {
                   $this->session->set_userdata($data);
                   redirect('site1/members_area');
                }
                else  if ($status == 'inactive')//Account In active
                {  $this->inactive();
                  }
                  else // incorrect username or password
            {
                $this->invalid();
            }
            }

        }   

    function inactive()
        {
        echo"<script>alert('In active user Please contact the administrator');</script>";
        $this->load->view('login_form'); 
        }
        function invalid()
        {
        echo"<script>alert('Invalid username or password');</script>";
        $this->load->view('login_form'); 
        }
```

site1

```
function members_area()
    {
        $this->load->view('index');


    }
```

model:

```
function validate()
    {
        $this->db->where('username', $this->input->post('username'));
        $this->db->where('password', md5($this->input->post('password')));
            $this->db->where('college_name', $this->input->post('college_name'));
        $query = $this->db->get('membership');

        return $query;

    }
```

Comment: You've got an awful mix of display and business logic going on. You should really separate your back- and front-end logic, you're not really using the MVC separation codeigniter tries to provide right now.

Comment: Your code seems OK. I think the problem is from your values and or your conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function validate_credentials()
    {   $this->load->helper('url');

        $this->load->model('membership_model');
        $query = $this->membership_model->validate();

        if($query) // if the user's credentials validated...
        {
            $data = array(
                'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
                'is_logged_in' => true
            );
             $data1 = array(
                'college_name' => $this->input->post('college_name'),
                'is_logged_in' => true
            );
             $this->session->set_userdata($data1);

            if($query->num_rows()>0){
             $status = $query->row()->account_status;}
            else {
             $status = ''; }
             //Account active
            if($status == 'active')
            {
               $this->session->set_userdata($data);
               redirect('site1/members_area');
            }
            else  if ($status == 'inactive')//Account In active
            {  $this->inactive();
              }
              else // incorrect username or password
        {
            $this->invalid();
        }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your model

```
return $query->num_rows();
```

In your controller replace if($query) by

```
if($query>0){ ..... your code ....}
```

Comment: did you tried echo $query->num_rows(); ? what is it returning?

Comment: instead of return $query; i placed return $query->num_rows(); .It is not returning anything.without entering username , password and college name it moves to the page

Comment: print your query with echo $this->db->last_query(); and check this query in phpmyadmin and see what it the result. Also echo $query->num_rows(); after printing the query.